# How to do a + (sum) operation on a list by grouping

Tags: c#, logic

I'm trying to add up the totals by category, but I'm not getting the right result in page cshtml.

I tried:

```
 <span style="font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif !important ; font-size: 18px !important ; color: #4CAF50 !important ; font-weight: 700 !important ; float: right !important">
                                Total:
                                <span style="color: #212121 !important">
                                    @{

                                        var agrupamentoPorCategoria = Model.itens.GroupBy(c => c.idCategoria);
                                        string totalPorCategoria = "";

                                        foreach (var itensPorCategoria in agrupamentoPorCategoria)
                                        {
                                            totalPorCategoria = itensPorCategoria.Sum(s => s.vSubTotal).ToString("N2");
                                        }

                                        //var totalPorCategoria = Model.itens.Sum(s => s.vSubTotal);
                                    }

                                    @totalPorCategoria
                                </span>
</span>
```

[image]

The expected result is to sum up the subtotal column by grouping the category.

In the example above the image the value would have to be 5,557.55

Comment: You're loop is going to just take the last grouping and sum it.  Instead you need to filter on the current category and do the sum on that.  Something like `var totalPorCategoria = Model.itens.Where(c => c.idCategoria == currentId).Sum(s => s.vSubTotal);`.  Or really you should be doing the grouping first, then loop over the groups and create the output for each group and calcualte the sum at the end.  We'd need to see more of our code to see how you're currently handling that.

Comment: Thanks, it worked perfectly! Put your solution as an answer for me to signal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to select all items and then perform the sum. This should work:

```
var totalPorCategoria = Model.itens.Where(c => c.idCategoria == currentId).Sum(s => s.vSubTotal);
```